# How to formulate on specific dates

Tags: if-statement, sum, formula, crystal-reports-2008

Lets say I have 5 invoices each having a total of 100
4 of the invoices are in the month of Jan and 1 in the month of Feb
I would like to sum ONLY the 4 invoices of Jan thereby giving me a total of 400

I would expect to write a formula such as if invoice.date in period 01.01.2015 to 31.01.2015 then sum invoice.total

however when I try this, the result is 500 as it's totalling all invoices and note only the 4 in the period.

Comment: What platform/language/tool is this?

Comment: Excellent task for Sherlock Holmes.

Comment: Sorry. I am trying this using Crystal Reports V12 connected to an Oracle DB.